# C# regular express for list ips 65.232.211.[001-175]

Tags: regex, ip-address

I want to match IP against my IP list which stored in arraylist but it is in this format
`65.232.211.[001-175]`

eg. `68.232.211.133` must be match 
    `68.232.211.199` not match

I want regualr express for this scenario but I dont know how it would be..
I tried but not getting correct ans..
Please help me..

Comment: which language are you using ? you should use substring instead of regex

Comment: C# substring is also ok but i want to check all from 001 - 175 [001/175] thats why i thought regularexpression is more better

Comment: you can find last number (find last dot and then last number) in your ip, and then - check. i will do it with substring, cause i know, that substring use only one (!) reading of string to catch last number.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like so: `68\\.232\\.211\\.0*([1-9][0-9]?|1[0-6][0-9]|17[0-5])`. The last part should match the numerical range you are after (courtesy of [Regex_For_Range](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range)).

Since the period character in regex is a special character (denoting any character), it needs to be escaped. This is done by adding an extra slash, like so: `\.`. Since you are using C# (it seems) you need to escape the slash as well since that is a special character in the C# language.

You could, alternatively (and even better than the above) use the following regex to split the IP in 2 and do what ever validation you need: `^([\d.]+?)\.(\d+)$`. This regex would yield 2 groups, so taking `68.232.211.133` as an example, it would yield `68.232.211` and `133`.

The above will allow you to match the initial part of the IP as a string and it will then allow you to take the last section of the IP, change it to a numerical value and perform range checks using mathematical operator.

In my opinion, the second approach should be favoured since it is (in my opinion) easier to maintain.

Comment: I tried with 68\\.232\\.211\\.([1-9][0-9]?|1[0-6][0-9]|17[0-5]) this regular expression but its not worked   I want to check 68.232.211.133 match with 68.232.211.[001-175]  and 68.232.211.205 will not match with 68.232.211.[001-175] because 205 is not in between 001 to 175

Comment: @user1501101: I have modified my answer please see if it helps.